# MySQL query join on max value

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Slimmed down example of my query;

```
SELECT ce.*, cev.*
FROM calendar_event ce
INNER JOIN calendar_event_viewing cev
on ce.calendar_event_id = cev.calendar_event_viewing_calendar_event_id AND calendar_event_viewing_type='2'
WHERE (calendar_event_viewing_public_notes='Unable to reach viewer to obtain feedback yet, will keep trying.' OR calendar_event_viewing_public_notes='Unable to reach viewer to obtain feedback yet, voicemail left, will keep trying.')
ORDER BY calendar_event_start ASC
```

The table `calendar_event_viewing` can have more than one entry. I want to select the latest entry as part of the inner join. The latest entry would have the highest value for `calendar_event_viewing_calendar_event_id`. By default, if there was more than one row to join on in `calendar_event_viewing`, what row would MySQL choose?

Comment: *The table calendar_event_viewing can have more than one entry. The latest entry would have the highest value for calendar_event_viewing_calendar_event_id*. But you are joining on `calendar_event_viewing_calendar_event_id`. This does not really make sense to me.

Comment: You probably want to use another column to identify the *latest entry*. Also, you maybe have more than one record in `calendar_event` per `calendar_event_viewing_calendar_event_id`,

Answer (score 0):

You can do a subquery in your query to just return the latest `calendar_event_viewing`

```
SELECT ce.*, cev.*
FROM calendar_event ce
INNER JOIN (SELECT * 
            FROM calendar_event_viewing
            GROUP BY calendar_event_viewing_calendar_event_id
            ORDER BY **id** DESC) cev
on ce.calendar_event_id = cev.calendar_event_viewing_calendar_event_id AND calendar_event_viewing_type='2'
WHERE (calendar_event_viewing_public_notes='Unable to reach viewer to obtain feedback yet, will keep trying.' OR calendar_event_viewing_public_notes='Unable to reach viewer to obtain feedback yet, voicemail left, will keep trying.')
ORDER BY calendar_event_start ASC
```

Replace `**id**` with what ever column denotes the latest.